# Embedding in TensorFlow Functional API with 200.000 different words dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, word-embedding

I have checked several questions in Stakoverflow and tutorials about Keras and TensorFlow embedding but I have found no answer that works for me. I explain.

I have 200.000 words dictionary. With 10376 unique "words". They represent Cellular device ID. IMEI. In this particular instance, I want to process them using Keras Functional API and then merge with the numerical data eventually when I solve this.

But I can pass the first level which part which is the embedding.

Here the code

```
#example of device
0         jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==
1         jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==
2         jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==
3         chIM3a44QxatbmmjyBFGDQ==
4         PdhyfpkIT8Weslb54thwuQ==
5         lrDcRnK7RtKkvaqaYjliBQ==

#lenght of the device 
device_len = len(device)
device_len
200000
#uniques device inside the 200000
top_words = len(np.unique(device))
top_words
10376

#keras encoded
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, top_words) for d in device]

#max length of the vector for each word
max_length = 2
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
print(padded_doc)

[[10269  9475]
 [10269  9475]
 [10269  9475]
 ...
 [ 1340  2630]
 [ 7270     0]
 [ 2364  9298]]

#converted to tensors
padded_docs = tf.convert_to_tensor(padded_docs)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(padded_docs.eval())
sess.close()

#here is the networks
top_words = 10376
embedding_vector_length = 2
x = Embedding(top_words, embedding_vector_length)(padded_docs)
x = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
modelx = Model(inputs=padded_docs, outputs = x)
```

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(200000, 2), dtype=int32) (missing previous layer metadata).
```

I check similar questions and answers but I can't find something that works for me.

If someone can help me will be greatly appreciated

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `Input` for your model. `padded_docs` is not a tensor, it's "data".

```
 from keras.layers import Input

 inputs = Input((doc_length,))
 x = Embedding(top_words, embedding_vector_length)(inputs)
 x = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)

 modelx = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs = x)
```

Also, you need that `padded_docs` be made of "integers", not of one-hot encodings. The `Embedding` layer needs integers.

It's important to notice that you will not pass it as a tensor, but as a regular numpy array, to train with `model.fit`.

So you need to remove the `one_hot` and `convert_to_tensor` parts.

Then you will do a `model.fit(padded_docs, whatever_outputs, .....etc....)`

Comment: The original data is a string of numbers and letters like this jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==. How I convert that to integers then if not one hoe encoders? Any help will be appreciated Daniel :)

Comment: Isn't `d` an integer?

Comment: ```encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, top_words) for d in device]``` ```device``` is a string and ```d``` is not an integer
And this is the problem I had all along with this project. If I do this with Sequential() it works but if I do with Functional API it does not. And I am forced to do with Functional because the dataset is very mixed. Sorry about the late replay. Different time zones. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If it works with `Sequential`, then it definitely works with Functional, you only need the `Input` tensor, as both answers here show.

Comment: If you are keeping `padded_docs` as a tensor, an `Input(tensor=padded_docs)` may work.

Comment: I have noticed that if work in Sequential() does not necessarily work in Functional This is the new mistake I have. Sorry for all this but I have been stuck in this for a while: TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RefVariable

I have update the code to better show the type of data

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Model, the input should be an Input layer, not a tensor.

```
input = keras.layers.Input((max_length,))
x = Embedding(top_words, embedding_vector_length)(input)
x = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
modelx = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
```

Comment: I did as you suggest and I have a new error:     ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("dense/Sigmoid:0", shape=(200000, 2, 2), dtype=float32)
Can you help? Please?

Comment: @Gabriel Sorry, I missed that part. See edit. I changed the input to the embedding layer from `padded_docs` to the input layer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Still got an error and I copy your code.                 
 AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks' Is regarding the embedding part

Comment: @Gabriel Not 100% sure how to fix that, but that's a separate issue. Google it, and if you still need help ask a new question here on Stack Overflow. Also, another unrelated thing: `maxlen` in `pad_sequences` is the final length of your sequences, not the size of your embedding vectors.

Comment: Thank you. I will